# How to select the particular row using where clauses in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have number of records in table. Assume that duration field has value of 70,180,280,380 and so on.

Now i want to get the record of duration 100. It is between 70 and 180 so i want to get the details of 180 duration  field values but it is not get the values from above 180.

It is possible please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM table T1 INNER JOIN table T2 on T2.duration - T1.duration >= 100
WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID + 1
ORDER BY T1.duration
```

Hoping it will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

From what you've said:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `duration`>70 AND `duration`<=180
```